# Is it possible to run Android Emulator(AVD) on Linux based AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-linux

I have been exploring about Jenkins hosting on AWS. For running my Jenkins job on AWS EC2 instance, I want few tools to be configured in the EC2 server. My prerequisites include, setting up Appium and AVD emulator on the existing Linux instance. Once my Jenkins job is triggered, my code checkout should happen and my automation testcases should execute in the emulator which is located on the Jenkins server( which is the EC2 Linux instance). I would like to know, if running AVD is possible on Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

For running it in Ec2 linux you need to run the emulator without skin.
Options:

1. There is a Plugin in Jenkins for this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=57181910
2. Use docker containers with android emulators and jenkins. However I would still recommend using emulator plugin in them as well. Example image: https://hub.docker.com/r/bertrandmartel/docker-jenkins-android

Comment: @srinidhi If this works for you then don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer so that others coming this way can know.